# Laravel, Behat, Faker and GuzzleHttp - DB Rollback before I can get the data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, behat, faker

I'm try to create a fake data for testing, and have the following code on the Behat Context

```
$modelFake = factory(User::class)->create();        
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', url($this->apiURL . '/user/' . $modelFake->id));
```

After the class declaration I have:

```
use DatabaseTransactions;
```

The user fake it's created and I get the current Id to do the request, but the code return an empty object, If I remove the `use DatabaseTransactions;` the user persist on the database and the request return the object, but I can't realize what is my issue.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Regards

**Edit:**

When I try to get the user `User::find($modelFake->id)` I'm getting the object :(

Why when I made the request I can't get the object?

**Edit 2:**

The main problem it's the data persist only on the context and the request belong to another instance of the DB

Comment: Is it possible that you're running the tests in a DEV or TEST environment, while your webserver is actually running in a PROD environent. Which implies that all queries you're doing while you're running the tests will end up happening on your test db, where the queries on your webserver are actually happening on your prod/dev DB. Just a thought

Comment: No it in the same environment, I know the issue.. I run behat (console) and the DB start a new "DB session" (ex sessionBehat), so when I made the request to the URL, the site create another "DB session" (ex sessionRequest) so, I create the userModel only on sessionBehat, and sessionRequest doesn't know about that userModel so....

EDIT:
Possible solution: remove `use DatabaseTransactions` create the the user, request the url and then remove the user... I don't like it but for now it's the only solution I found